# how to get around cakephp by include for fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

I'm trying to add fullcalendar into my cakephp project.
But, the system fails by including some files by a javascript from fullcalendar.

I found via the console of Google Chrome that the page is loading; but when i open the page I get the following:

```
Missing Controller
Error: IncludesController could not be found.

Error: Create the class IncludesController below in file: app\Controller\IncludesController.php

<?php
class IncludesController extends AppController {

}
Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app\View\Errors\missing_controller.ctp

Stack Trace
```

So... The page is loading... But... CakePHP stops it... How can I get around cakephp to let my javascript load the files?

Many thanks!!!!

**EDIT**

When i load the page I get this message from chrome's console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)    

http://localhost/projects/cake/clean/vendors/includes/cal_events.php?   
start=1380405600&end=1384038000&_=1382911071971
```

The location of the cal_events.php is:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\cake\clean\Vendor\includes\cal_events.php
```

Content of cal_events.php is:

```
<?php

    // Loader - class and connection
    include('loader.php');

    echo $calendar->json_transform();

?>
```

The javascript who loads this files:

```
    var defaults = 
    {
        calendarSelector: '#calendar',

        timeFormat: 'H:mm - {H:mm}',

        ajaxJsonFetch: 'vendors/includes/cal_events.php',
```

I hope this is good...
Again... Many thanks!

Comment: where's the code??? Impossible to troubleshoot from error only

Comment: The code is not the problem. I tried to explain that cakephp blocks the 'include' from the fullcalendar javascript. I am looking for a way to get around cakephp when the js loads.

Comment: js runs in browser, php runs in server. No idea what you mean by cake blocks js..... they run in completely different environments and are completely exclusive of each other

Comment: Okay. Sorry for the bad explanation. The javascript calls a php page. Okay? The problem is, is that cakephp thinks it is a normal page; so he gives an error (i placed above). Do you understand? Sorry for bad explanation!

Comment: sounds like url you are using in ajax is wrong...again....need some code to inspect

Comment: Sorry... See above!!!

Comment: could be htacess issue when you are trying to access a php file outside of cake in the `'includes` folder. Makes more sense sending your data from a cake controller. WHat happens when you try opening the `cal_events.php` in browser ? Paste that whole link including query string into address bar

Comment: _WHat happens when you try opening the cal_events.php in browser ?_ See the code above; missing controller error. A htaccess issue could be possible! How to solve that? It would be professional to keep it into the framework... Thanks for the reply!

Comment: you solve it by using the framwork...not trying to bypass it! use a controller to send data. htaccess is there for security so nobody can access files they aren't supposed to. For simple test, if you placed the file in root it would likely work but overall makes little sense to be using a framework then try hacking around it

Comment: Thanks for the smart reply. You are right that I have to solve it by USING the framework an not BYPASSING it :P. I guess i have to change the javascript code?

Comment: I wasn't trying to be smart... but what you have been trying to do makes no sense at all